# What are common ill-conditioned matrices in linear system?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods

Matrix condition number is very important because many problems are ill-conditioned and cannot be reliably solved using double precision computer systems.

Here is what I know that could happen in linear model, that the problem is ill-conditioned and R solve function cannot handle.

- Case 1: using raw polynomial expansion
- Case 2: using almost identical features

[image]

- Hilbert matrix is another ill-conditioned problem but less likely to see in real world.

What are other matrices that we may encounter in the linear system that are ill-conditioned?

Comment: I am sorry, but the code given (in which language ?) is impossible for me to understand.

Comment: He mentions it is using "R".

Comment: sorry, I originally asked this question in statistics community and got closed, so I asked here. The code is just generate some random matrix, use polynomial expansion / generate similar columns, and calculate condition number.